# Can't login in incognito mode in Chrome - ReactJS App Google Login

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-signin, react-google-login

I'm facing a serious issue that I couldn't find any correct answers. Basically, I'm developing a ReactJS app and I'm using **GoogleLogin** from ***'react-google-login'*** library for app's authentication.
As mentioning on the title, I can't login to my app in private mode. Console keeps returning this message:

[image]

Based on my researches, people usually recommend to **`Go to Settings --> Allow all third party cookies`** to fix the issue. But from a developer perspective, this is not what I want because I need my users can freely login to my app using Google without telling them to go to the Settings Site.

I see some pages like: Freepik, Youtube,... they currently allow user to login in private mode, so there must be another way to fix this issue.

I have tried to research but I didn't find any correct solutions for what I want.

I expect to have at least a correct authentication Google Sign-in flow, or right operations, endpoints, documents,..., which I can implement it using code.

Here is my Google Sign-in code as well:

[image]